# Pandas str.replace method regex flag raises inconsistent exceptions

Tags: python, pandas

When I use the `regex=[True|False]` flag in the `pd.Series.str.replace()` method, I get contradictory exceptions:

- `repl` is a dictionary => it says `repl must be a string or callable`
- `repl` is a callable => it says `Cannot use a callable replacement when regex=False`

I'm trying to replace the month part of a Spanish date from a DataFrame index with the corresponding English short name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the months' short names in English and Spanish
ENG = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
ESP = ['ENE', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'ABR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AGO', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DIC']

# Dictionary mapping Spanish months to English months
esp2eng = dict(zip(ESP, ENG))

# Function to make the dictionary "callable"
def eng_from_esp(key):
    return esp2eng[key]

# Create the DF with date in the "%d-%b-%y" format as index, where %b is the Spanish naming
idx = ['06-{}-19'.format(m) for m in ESP]
col = ['ordinal']
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((12, 1)),
                   index=idx,
                   columns=col)

data.index.str.replace('ENE', esp2eng, regex=False)
TypeError: repl must be a string or callable

data.index.str.replace('ENE', eng_from_esp, regex=False)
ValueError: Cannot use a callable replacement when regex=False
```

Comment: From the docs for [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), `repl` can be a *string or callable* but a dictionary is not supported. This is the first check that's done. The regex flag is checked *after*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) you will see that the `repl` argument can be a *string or callable*, but a `dict` is not supported.

With that in mind, your first attempt is not supported.

Digging into the source code (key parts reproduced below), you still see that the check for `string` or `callable` is done *first*, before checking the `regex` flag.

```
# Check whether repl is valid (GH 13438, GH 15055)
if not (is_string_like(repl) or callable(repl)):
    raise TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")

if regex:
    # omitted
else:
    # omitted
    if callable(repl):
        raise ValueError("Cannot use a callable replacement when "
                         "regex=False")
```

So your first attempt (using a dictionary for `repl`) trips the first `if` check prints the message that `"repl must be a string or callable"`.

Your second attempt passes this check, but then gets tripped by the check for a callable inside the `else` block of the `regex` check.

So in short, there is no inconsistency. Sure the first error message *could* potentially be improved to say something like `"repl must be a string or callable (unless you're using regex=False)"` but that's not really necessary.

---

FWIW, here is a pandas "one-liner" that should achieve the desired result:

```
print(
    data.reset_index()
        .replace(esp2eng, regex=True)
        .set_index("index", drop=True)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=0)
)
#           ordinal
#06-JAN-19        0
#06-FEB-19        1
#06-MAR-19        2
#06-APR-19        3
#06-MAY-19        4
#06-JUN-19        5
#06-JUL-19        6
#06-AUG-19        7
#06-SEP-19        8
#06-OCT-19        9
#06-NOV-19       10
#06-DEC-19       11
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Even though I had already found a way of making it work using `pd.Series.str.replace()`, I really appreciate the alternative solution using `pd.Series.replace()`. I'm not sure whether it makes sense to add it here as a separate answer, though. That would probably steer the conversation away from its main subject (i.e. inconsistent exceptions).